# Loops and counting

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, count, prompt

I want to make it so when someone answers the prompt they can answer a number 1 through 6 and to exit to just enter 0. After that I want them to be able to enter a number and that number will be correlated to an image or a link. Example: I have 3 different kinds of candy and I want 1 to be skittles, 2 to be m&ms, and 3 to be jolly ranchers. When the user enters 1 they will have an image come up that is skittles, and when they enter 2 an image of m&ms will come up. This is the code I have so far. If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it!

```
var stop = '0'   

while(true) {
    var input = prompt('Give a number 1 through 6. Type 0 to exit.');
    if(input === stop){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the images in an array, then use the input as the array index. Since array indexes start at 0, you'll need to subtract 1.

Comment: What are you counting?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of image urls and select any of them by the number the user has entered.

```
var images = ['xxx.jpg','yyy.jpg', 'zzz.jpg']
var stop = '0'   

while(true) {

    var input = prompt('Give a number 1 through 6. Type 0 to exit.');

    if(input === stop){
        break;
    }
    else{
     
       if (!IsNaN(input) && images.length >= input)
          showImage(images[input - 1]);   //a mock function
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I added the array. for the "images.length" part in the if statement at the bottom is that a thing that is put in the css file with the image length and height? I'm sorry I'm new to this. I just started getting into JavaScript a few days ago. I'm trying to break down what that mock function does so I understand it. So far it hasn't worked so I'm missing something somewhere. Thank you!

Comment: The `showImage` is a mock function. The possible code that goes inside the function would be to set an image to an `img` element via its `src` attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm slow. So inside the mock function where the images element is I put the folder with the images I want? Or would I put src in the var images = [...] in there? I'm sorryy.

Comment: I entered "showImage(<img src="xxx.jpg"></img>,  [input  - 1]);" for all of the images changing the input everytime.  That is correct? I did use my actual file name of course. Now the prompt isn't coming up and I checked everything make sure everything looked like your code. I'm sorry. Thank you so much for your info though!!

Comment: That's wrong. You need to follow some tutorials step by step. Use w3 schools tutorial and  go through it.

Comment: @AdaraT. did you program a function called showImage? It is just a placeholder to show where you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach your problem like this. Just catch the input and process it inside your while loop.

```js
var pictures = [...] // array of pictures

while(true){

    var input = prompt('Give a number 1 through 6. Type 0 to exit.');
    if(input === '0'){
        break;
    }else{
        if(pictures.length >= input) {
             showMyImage(pictures[input - 1])
             // or do anything else with your image (e.g. error handling etc.)
        }
    }


}
```

Hope this can help!